# ASP.NET Publish FTP Issues

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, ftp, hosting

I am going round and round with my ASP.NET hosting company. I have created a simple web app using Visual Studio 2012 .NET Framework 4.5

At first I tried to use web deploy to publish my website, not even with their documentation could I get this accomplished. Then they had me use the FTP option to publish. That worked good, I could publish to the root of my domain. But when I tried to publish to a different folder domain.com/apps/root/thisapp, Visual Studio would publish without error, but when I navigated to the URL, I recived an 500 server error.

Now I was asked to just use an FTP program and copy all my files to the directory that I want the site in, so I did and now I get an "Configuration Error" on my web.config file:

```
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:


Line 21:       </namespaces>
Line 22:     <controls><add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" /></controls></pages>
Line 23:     <authentication mode="Forms">
Line 24:       <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" />
Line 25:     </authentication>
```

I don't get this error locally, nor when the site was published at the root of my domain. I am running out of ideas, and seems my host is too. Does anyone know how you publish your site to any directory you want on an ASP.NET server?

Also could someone help me with narrowing down what is causing this error? The hosting support, says it is the code or my project. However I don't think this is so, since it works fine locally and at the root of domain. I think there is an issue with IIS or permissions on my folder(s).

Comment: What's the error you get on that line?

Comment: @MikeChristensen Sorry, it is an Configuration Error.

Comment: It just says "Configuration Error" and nothing else?  Someone really needs to yell at the .NET team for *that* error message.

Comment: @MikeChristensen Yeah there is more then that let me edit my post, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Web.config has certain sections that are only allowable at specific levels in the IIS hierarchy.  The basic levels are Machine, Application, and Everywhere (for specific definitions, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.sectiondefinition.allowdefinition%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)).

The issue is that your web.config contains some sections that are only allowed in the Machine or Application levels.  Machine is pretty much off limits (unless you own the machine, but you have a hosting provider).  Application requires that your folder be either the root of your IIS site, or a subdirectory marked as an Application in IIS ([possibly relevant link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772042%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)).

Try asking your provider how you can specify a directory to be marked as an Application.  If they don't allow this, you'll have to dig around the web.config and find which settings have this level of security set.

Comment: You have a very good point as well. Thank you for this. I have contacted my host, and I have shared this question with them. I will let you know what they come back with.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if by "web deploy" you mean Web Matrix 3 or not. If not, it should solve your problem. I was having that problem by hosting company and I was using an ASP.NET MVC 4 internet App. http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/

Hope this helps,

Rock

Comment: Never heard of this web matrix before I will give it a shot. This is what I was referring to here: http://blog.arvixe.com/arvixe-asp-net-web-deployment-how-to-guide/

Comment: Good luck! Let me know how it goes and if you need any help just let me know here =]

Comment: I can't use web deploy. I have to use FTP. Under web deploy (even with web matrix 3) It says I have the wrong user name and or password. The web matrix looks just like the visual studio built in publisher. How would I tell web matrix to publish to a folder under my domain? In site path or destination URL? Or do it for both like, site path /domain.com/wwwroot/somefolder and destination URL http://www.domain.com/somefolder?

Answer (score 0):

You should disable web.config inheritance:

You could read more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.inheritinchildapplications(v=vs.110).aspx